# How to paginate images from photo library in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have imported images from photoLibrary in UICollectionView and the collectionView take a lot of time to initial the photo inside the collectionView so I need to pagination these images by vertical scroll firstly I want to load in collectionView 10 images then the user paginate load 10 images and the process continue

```
import UIKit
import Photos
import XLPagerTabStrip

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class PhotosRecyclerCollection: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var imageArray = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        grabPhotos()
    }

    func grabPhotos(){

        let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

        if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions) {

            if fetchResult.count > 0 {

                for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{

                    imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {

                        image , error in

                        self.imageArray.append(image!)
                    })
                }
            }

            else {

                print("You got no photos")

                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }





    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotosCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotosCollectionViewCell

        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

        imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width = collectionView.frame.width / 4 - 1


        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)



    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let desVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageCropper") as! ImageCropperViewController
        desVC.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(desVC, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to paginate. It takes a lot of time to load because you are preloading all the images.

Simply stop preloading the images in memory and just get the relevant image when it is actually needed.

To do so add `fetchResult` as an instance variable:

```
private var fetchResult: PHFetchResult?
```

Replace

```
if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions) {

            if fetchResult.count > 0 {

                for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{

                    imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {

                        image , error in

                        self.imageArray.append(image!)
                    })
                }
            }
```

with

```
if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
{
    self.fetchResult = fetchResult
}
```

Replace `return imageArray.count` with `return self.fetchResult?.count ?? 0`

And finally:

```
let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
```

with

```
imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult!.object(at: i) as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { image , error in
    let currentIndexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
    if (currentIndexPath.compare(indexPath) == .orderedSame) {
        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = image

    }
})
```

Comment: when I scroll collectionView, my images refreshing after few millisecond, first shows random image and then change to actual image.